# How can I take a screenshot of a web element from ruby gem selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering How can I take a screenshot of a web element from ruby gem selenium-webdriver ? I am aware of taking screenshot of complete page but what I want is to take screenshot of a portion of the page.

Comment: please give one screenshots for the same....

Comment: sorry but I can't share the image because it contain confidential information.

Comment: Assume I want to take screenshot of text box element on google home page. How can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @toro2k It is not duplicate.. that question and this question is totally different..

Comment: You can take help from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/selenium-users/image/selenium-users/8atiPIh39OY/S2NVGiKQbuYJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/7wHF0nGuOV0), [here](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/197) . Codes are written probably in Java. You need to translate this to Ruby. If you can do it successfully,please post your answer here. In the meantime if I can,I will do it.

Comment: I will try the above suggestions and get back to this question.